# Swapping Samsung EVO 980 from Intel to AMD chipset

Tags: windows-10, ssd, pci-express

I'm planning to upgrade the SSD in my Lenovo X1 Carbon (4th Gen) with either a Samsung EVO 970 Plus or an EVO 980 PRO. My X1 carbon has an M.2 PCIe 3.0 x4, so if I get the EVO 980 PRO, I won't be able to take full advantage of the drive's speeds. In the future, is it possible to take the 980 out of my laptop and place into a new laptop (theoretically with PCIe 4.0) and have everything work without reformatting and reinstalling Windows 10? Note that I'll be taking it out of an Intel based laptop and hopefully placing it into a new AMD Ryzen based laptop in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Its unlikely the SSD will be the problem, however I predict a lot of pain from the OS side because of Windows drivers and licensing.  (This would be a lot easier under Linux).

Depending on your workload (not good for games) you.might be able to get a good part of the way there by installing Linux (because no license issues and lots of driver support in the kernel/supplied modules) and then running Windows in a VM.  In this way you could abstract away a lot of the driver issues Windows has - for example by having Windows use Virtual (eg KVM) abstracted drivers.

In reality though a clean OS reinstall may be a better option of you need best performance.